# Connect Moveit to a robot

Tags: ros, moveit, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I'm looking for any tutorials or any documents that show how to connect Moveit to a robot. I'm working actually on self-collision robot so I have to work with real robot using what I did on Moveit.
Or any other software instead of Moveit is welcome too :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203132/connect-moveit-to-a-robot/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2015-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have not actually done it yet, but I know of a package which includes such behavior [CentroEPiaggio/kuka-lwr](https://github.com/CentroEPiaggio/kuka-lwr). It is an ros + gazebo package for the LWR4 kuka and they seem to have MoveIt working with the real robot. Have a look there.

---

Originally posted by [gpldecha](https://answers.ros.org/users/20741/gpldecha/) with karma: 285 on 2015-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0